# CodeIgniter - Smarty - How to fetch templates into a master template from one place in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, smarty, fetch

It's a little bit hard to explain what's my question about but I going to try :)

In custom projects where I'm using Smarty, I have an index.php file where all the basic settings for url handling and stuff is placed.

For example:

```
// Get information for the "about us" page

if($_GET['qs']=='about_us'){
  $data['text'] = 'Lorem Ipsum...';
  $data['other_stuff'] = 'dolor sit amet';

  // Required template file
  $data['tpl_Name'] = 'about.tpl';
}
```

At the bottom of this file I have a bit of code that fetches the correct template end sends it to a master_site template.

For example:

```
if (isset($data['tpl_Name'])){
  $this->smarty->assign('content', $this->smarty->fetch($data['tpl_Name'])); 
  $this->smarty->view('master_site.tpl');
}
```

In the master_site.tpl I can access the about.tpl by using {$content}
This {$content} variable will change for every page because the index.php is the page where all the data will be send to by requesting a page in my application.

**Question**: Is there a file in CodeIgniter thats available on every page so I can create something like above? Right now I have to use this piece of code (second example) in every function of my controller and that seems inefficient.

Of course i have to set $data['tpl_Name'] in every function but thats no problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered extending the core controller?

Comment: The way I would do it, is move all the page information out to CSV file (i.e. sitemap.csv). Then load the csv file in the constructer function as an array. You could then route all page requests to one method, dynamically set the templates based on the uri (as you already do), but also request the page information from the sitemap.csv array in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of ways to integrate a template library into CodeIgniter, and a lot of it depends on how you want to tie your templates together. The following may suit you well, or maybe just point you in the right direction. It's not the only Smarty/CI solution to templates, but it's the one I'm familiar with.

[I wrote some code to integrate Smarty into CI](https://github.com/cryode/CodeIgniter_Smarty). It allows you to use the standard way of loading views -- `$this->load->view('view', $data)` -- but you get to use Smarty's syntax within the files.

The way I handled a "master" template is through Smarty's `{extends}` ([template inheritance docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl)). The individual views that I load all extend either a main template, or some other hierarchy that leads to one.

**main_template.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta>
    <meta>
    <title>{$title|default:"Default Title"}</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Page Link</li>
        <li>Page Link</li>
        <li>Page Link</li>
        <li>Page Link</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="main-content">

{block name=content}{/block}

</section>

<footer>
    &copy; 2013 Me!
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**page.php:**

```
{extends "main_template.php"}

{block "content"}

<h2>My Content Page</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum and stuff...</p>

{/block}
```

The `$title` variable would be added to your view data like normal, and you'd load the page with the standard syntax:

```
$data['title'] = 'My page';

$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

I'll let you investigate the Smarty docs to get more in-depth details, but that's what I've done before. :)